# MongoDB inserts slow down when in Replica Set mode

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I'm running MongoDB 2.4.5 and recently I've started digging into Replica Set to get some kind of redundancy.

I started same mongo instance with *--replSet* parameter and also added an Arbiter to running Replica Set. What happened was writing to mongo slowed down significantly (from 15ms to 30-60ms, sometimes even around 300ms). As soon as I restarted it in not-replicaset-mode performance went back to normal.

I also set up the newest 3.0 version of MongoDB with no data and run same tester as before and the result was quite similar - writes were at least 50% slower while running the ReplicaSet mode.

I could not find many examples of such behaviour online so I guess something is wrong with my mongo configuration or OS configuration.

Any ideas? Thanks for help.

Comment: do you pass any `write concern`, i.e. `{w: ?, j: ?}` parameters with your writes?

Comment: I use a C# lib to connect with mongo and use libs native writes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem was C# library. I used a native C# driver (works fine even with 2.4.5 MongoDB) and there seems to be no difference in performance. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're using "replica acknowledged" write concern, which means that the operation will not return until the data has been written to both the primary and replica. The write concern can be set when doing any write operation (from [2.6 onwards](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#rel-notes-write-operations) - it looks from the 2.4 documentation that [calling getLastError causes a write concern of replica acknowledged in 2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/write-concern/#available-write-concern), are you doing that in your test code?).

Read [this section (v3))](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#replica-acknowledged) or [this section (v2.4)](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/write-concern/#replica-acknowledged) of the MongoDB documentation to understand the implications of different write concerns and try explicitly setting it to Acknowledged.

Comment: Thanks for some helpful links, that lead me to the path of testing writes in the simplest way possible - with a JS script on localhost and remotely. There is no difference in performance between replicaset/standalone MongoDB. So probably my issue was caused by the C# lib, but i will also try to prove this.

Comment: +1 and besides the second part of write concern is the journaling setting. Its worth to take a look what is the default value of write concern for the c# driver.

Comment: Good point about the journalling settings - are there any specific replica-set-impacting journalling settings, @n9code ?

Comment: @Mark Hughes no, journaling write concern does not care if there is a replica set or not.